# Bootstrap 2 Glyphicons not working with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have bootstrap-sass 2.0 installed, and recently updated from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.1. Now the glyphicons don't work in production.

For example, no icon shows up for this:

```
<i class="icon-zoom-in"></i>
```

I tried installing the 'non-stupid-digest-assets' gem and also added the following line to production.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( '.woff', '.eot', '.svg', '.ttf' )
```

but they still don't work. How do I fix it? The bootstrap.css file is created from the gem, so I don't want to edit it directly.

**Update**

The issue is that the icons get CSS for an image that does not exist, such as:

```
background-image: url(/assets/glyphicons-halflings-d8bbe73c5fea83aefd24440ba9988084.png)
```

Below is part of my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.1'

gem 'rails', '4.1'
gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7' 
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.5'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'

gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.0.3' 

group :assets do  
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
    gem 'coffee-rails' 
    gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
    gem "non-stupid-digest-assets"
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: Can you share your Gemfile in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `'*.png'` to `config.assets.precompile` precompiled all the images and seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Manually place your icons within /vendor/assets/fonts for a quick fix.

Comment: I should download the icons from Glyphicons and put them directly in a fonts folder?

Comment: Traditionally I manually import all files including bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js, so I figure you just need to make them available.

Answer (score 0):

The following is from the Rails upgrade guide found at: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

> In Rails 4.0, precompiling assets no longer automatically copies
>   non-JS/CSS assets from vendor/assets and lib/assets. Rails application
>   and engine developers should put these assets in app/assets or
>   configure config.assets.precompile.

So make sure your 'bootstrap-sass' (version 2.0.0) gem has placed the assets in the app/assets directory.